# How i can place object in Scene? SpriteKit

Tags: xcode, swift

File GameScene have class GameScene, class GameScene have CirclePhysicsDefault:

```
func circlePhysicsDefault() {
var Circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 40)
Circle.position = CGPointMake(500, 500)
Circle.name = "defaultCircle"
Circle.strokeColor = SKColor.blackColor()
Circle.glowWidth = 10.0
Circle.fillColor = SKColor.yellowColor()
Circle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 40)
Circle.physicsBody.dynamic = true
self.addChild(Circle)
}
```

In file GameViewController i type:

```
@IBAction func addOneCircle(sender: AnyObject) {
GameScene().circlePhysicsDefault()
}
```

I linked this to button.

Run application, push the button - nothing happens.

If in GameScene function didMoveToView i call function circlePhysicsDefault, then app launch circle will be placed.

File GameViewController:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

/* Pick a size for the scene */
let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene")
// Configure the view.
let skView = self.view as SKView
skView.showsFPS = true
skView.showsNodeCount = true

/* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

/* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

skView.presentScene(scene)
}

@IBAction func addOneCircle(sender: AnyObject) {
GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene").circlePhysicsDefault()
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown.toRaw())
} else {
return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.toRaw())
}
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
} 
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
return false }
}
```

File GameScene:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        circlePhysicsDefault()
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }

    func sceneSetting() {
        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.grayColor()
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.01, -2)
        }
    func circlePhysicsDefault() {
        var Circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 40)
        Circle.position = CGPointMake(500, 500)
        Circle.name = "defaultCircle"
        Circle.strokeColor = SKColor.blackColor()
        Circle.glowWidth = 10.0
        Circle.fillColor = SKColor.yellowColor()
        Circle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 40)
        Circle.physicsBody.dynamic = true
        self.addChild(Circle)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are creating a new instance on key press, store a weak reference to the scene and call the method from the wished instance.

```
@IBAction func addOneCircle(sender: AnyObject) {
myGameSceneRef.circlePhysicsDefault()
}
```

So now please try the following:

```
@IBAction func addOneCircle(sender: AnyObject) {
    let scene = ((self.view as SKScene).scene as GameScene)
    scene.circlePhysicsDefault()
}
```

Or maybe change "let" to "var"

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing happened :( Can you give a more detailed answer? Please

Comment: I'll recreate it in swift and send you an example code in few minutes

Comment: Btw. why are you using let for the scene? Isn't let for immutable objects? where var is mutable

Comment: I have issue 'SKScene' does not have a member named 'circlePhysicsDefault' on 'scene.circlePhysicsDefault()' :(

Comment: sry my fault, i have updated my post. You have to use the scene as GameScene, because SKScene doesn't has such a method.

Comment: Thanks man! But i replaced SKScene on SKView and object will be placed on scene! :)